# Angular 2 external inputs

Tags: angular

Please can you help? Just starting with Angular 2 and having the following issue.

My component is below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myapp',
    inputs: ['mynumber']
})
@View({
    template: `<p>The next number is {{ mynumber + 1 }}</p>'
})
export class App {
    mynumber: number;
}
bootstrap(App);
```

Inside my HTML:

```
<myapp [mynumber]='41'></myapp>
```

But when run I get the following:

The next number is `NaN`

It looks simple but I am missing something. What I am trying to achieve is passing a value from outside the app into it.

Thanks.

Comment: That's an issue with setting inputs in the root component. Try passing `mynumber` in a child component and it should work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply but I am trying to  pass a  value from outside angular into it. Not sure how ? Cheers

Answer (score 11):

You can't specify property bindings (inputs) for the root component of your application. If you really want to specify some binding for it you should use additional component. See [this plunkers](http://plnkr.co/edit/WQoGwEeq9KL8DzQ2aDNY?p=preview).

```js
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp',
  template: `   
    <p>The next number is {{ mynumber + 1 }}</p>
  `
})
class App {
  @Input() mynumber: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  directives: [App],
  template: `
    <myapp [mynumber]="41"></myapp>
  `
})
export class Root {}
```

Comment: Cool . Thanks.  I thinking I am asking the impossible. I was hoping to feed in some data from other controls etc on the main html page. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

A workaround is reading it directly using `ElementRef`:

```
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef) {
  console.log(elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('someattribute'); 
}
```

and use it like

```
<myapp mynumber='41'></myapp>
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858

Answer (score 7):

Update to answers using ElementRef: use Renderer.selectRootElement instead.
Anyone trying to use ElementRef.nativeElement is probably seeing various warnings about how this is a last resort etc. Here is a modified, safer version.

```
constructor( renderer: Renderer ){
  let rootElement = renderer.selectRootElement('app-root');
  this.whateverInput = rootElement.getAttribute('my-attribute');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using angular 4 :
If you decide to use it as an attribute like that

```
    <myapp mynumber='41'></myapp>
```

You could just use the annotation @Attribute like that :

```
class Component {
    constructor(@Attribute('attributeName') public param:String){
        /** some process with your injected param **/
    }
}
```

Tested and worked successfully in my app.

Found the way there : https://gillespie59.github.io/2015/10/08/angular2-attribute-decorator.html