# Angular2 inject parent service into child

Tags: typescript, angular

Given I have simple `app` component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent}    from 'ng2-easy-table/app/app.component';
import {ConfigService} from "./config-service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [AppComponent],
  providers: [ConfigService],
  template: `
    <ng2-table [configuration]="configuration"></ng2-table>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor(private configuration:ConfigService) {}

}
bootstrap(App, []);
```

and `ng2-table`, which is being installed via `npm install`, and is placed in `node_modules` directory.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-table',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input configuration;
  constructor() {
    console.log("configuration: ", this.configuration); // <-- null
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("configuration: ", this.configuration); // <-- null
  }
}
```

and this config service:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    public searchEnabled = true;
    public orderEnabled = true;
    public globalSearchEnabled = true;
    public footerEnabled = false;
    public paginationEnabled = false;
    public exportEnabled = true;
    public resourceUrl = "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/E164yBM0l";
}
```

In the `app` component I put `ng2-table` component. `ng2-table` and `app` are root components, so I am not allowed to use `@Input()` (this is the reason why `[configuration]="configuration"` does not work (following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33155688/1168786). 
 The question is - how do I inject some service from `app` component into `ng2-table` component, but not using `@Input()`. 
How do I pass some config to my `ng2-table`, or even easier, how can I initialise component from `node_modules` which expects some config in constructor?

This is component link: https://github.com/ssuperczynski/ng2-easy-table/tree/master/app

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how the service instance from the parent is shared with the child component in this example: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Ah I think @James Salas answer answers my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Input` in `@Input configuration;` is missing `()` it should be

```
@Input() configuration;
```

I copied your code to the Plunker and adding `()` fixed it.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7nbtf?p=preview)

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how the service instance from the parent is shared with the child component in this example: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: I think @James Salas' answer is better than this one, and answers my question above as well.

Comment: But it doesn't answer the original question. Go with James' answer of course if it answers **your** question better.

Comment: no I think it is redundant to inject the service into the child, the instance is already shared

Answer (score 8):

Angular's dependency injection will provide the same instance of ConfigService to the child component as the parent component as long as it's not explicitly specified in the child component's `providers` property. This is due to Angular's hierarchal DI model, you can find more information in their [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html). Based on the code samples, it looks like `ConfigService` might not using DI so you might want to look at turning it into an Injectable as well: [DI info](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: Really nice article, will read it. After you answer I attached my `configService` to the question, I think is fine (hope so)

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the accepted one. Services should not be injected using input property. +1

Comment: @NarendraPathai yes I think you are right. I suppose you could inject the service via input property, but it would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't seem to be correct since I guess that you want to evaluate the `configuration` expression:

```
<ng2-table [configuration]="'configuration'"></ng2-table>
```

I would use the following instead

```
<ng2-table [configuration]="configuration"></ng2-table>
```

Moreover I would inject your service (if it's actually a service) this way:

```
(...)
import {ConfigService} from "./config-service";

export class App {
  constructor(private configuration: ConfigService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanky you Thierry for the answer, I tried your solution, bot still config is not being pass to child component. I edited a little bit question, because `console.log` is not showing `undefined` only `null`

Comment: You're welcome! Is your configuration object not null in the App component?

Comment: I would like to pass actually anything, even I am passing some string `<ng2-table [configuration]=" 'some_string' "></ng2-table>` I am getting `null`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply inject by constructor the service that you are providing in the parent component?

You don't need to define extra inputs to pass the configuration. That's not a good practice.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [AppComponent],
  providers: [ConfigService],
  template: `
    <ng2-table></ng2-table>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor(private configuration:ConfigService) {}

}
```

Then you can just inject the parent provider:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'ng2-table',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  constructor(private configuration:ConfigService) {
    console.log("configuration: ", this.configuration); // <-- null
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("configuration: ", this.configuration); // <-- null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FactoryProvider to provide the service from its parent.

```
export const LOCATION_SERVICE_PROVIDER: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: LocationService,
  deps: [
    [new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), LocationService],
  ],
  useFactory: function (
    parent: LocationService
  ) {
    return parent || new LocationService();
  }
};
```

Comment: This could use more context.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.