# Call a external function injected in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm searching a way for execute a external function in the main component of angular like this:

```
<head>  
  <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });

      function callback(datos){
        alert("datos: "+datos);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app [cb]="callback">loading...</my-app>
  </body>
```

And call this in the component like this:

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1 (click)="cb()">My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() cb;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Somebody know a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use bindings `[xxx]` (or `(xxx)`) on the root component. This only works inside Angular components.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/36997723/217408 or the answer linked to at the end might give you some ideas.

Comment: So, how can i call a external function in my components if i can't use the binding?

Comment: You can for example assign the function to `window` and then pass the name like `<my-app cb="callback">loading...</my-app>` and then get the name inside Angular like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36723603/217408 and call it like `window[cb]()`