# Can Angular 2 component interact with elements on index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I like to know if there is way to pre-write "dynamic" Angular 2 inputs and outputs on the index.html file, and the embedded Angular 2 app can bind with those elements?

i.e. index.html

```
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
   <div>{{getData}}</div>
   <button (click)="onTestGet()">Click me to test get data</button>
</body>
```

where the Angular 2 app will be rendered inside the `<my-app>` tag.

I have made the `{{getData}}` and the button worked well when they are inside the Angular template. But for now, when they are inside index.html, they are just dumb elements.

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported for security reasons.

If you want to register event handlers you need to do this imperatively with direct DOM access.

See also this similar question [Angular 2 external inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152914/angular-2-external-inputs)