# Angular 2: how to access to POST variables

Tags: javascript, angular, post

I have an Angular 2 application that needs to access to a JSON variable called "configuration" which has been passed as a "POST" parameter to the application itself.

With Angularjs, I used `ng-init` this way:

`<html lang="it" ng-app="myApp" ng-init='configuration=<%- configuration %>'>`

And I could access to that variable using `$scope.configuration`. But what about Angular 2? The only way I found to make this variable usable from the application is putting it inside a not-visible div, inside `index.html` page.

```
<body><div id="getConfig"><%- configuration %></div>
<app>Loading...</app>
</body>
```

And inside `app.component.ts`...

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app-fe/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

    private title:string = 'Hello World';
    private configuration = document.getElementById("getConfig").innerHTML;    

    constructor() {
    console.log('=== app started ===');
    console.log(this.configuration);
  };
}
```

But something tells me this is not the best way...

Comment: You can use APP_INITIALIZER, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method

Comment: Great! I used this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152914/angular-2-external-inputs

And it worked!
But any other ideas are accepted ;)