# Angular 2 element attributes

Tags: javascript, angular

When we call a component in Angular 2 like so `<my-component></my-component>`. Is it possible to pass in attrs here so that they can be used within the component class?

example:

```
<my-component data-is-live="true"></my-component>

// class
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log($attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 external inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152914/angular-2-external-inputs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614451/angular-2-input-binding-does-not-work/39614592#39614592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by simply specifying it as an input parameter:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <p>Is it live: {{isLive}} </p>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input('is-live') isLive: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.debug(this.isLive);
    }
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2E6XcNW6cTOblyhBOEwI?p=preview

**Note**

You can't use an attribute starting with `data-`, Angular2 seems to ignore those.

Comment: How can i access that var in the constructor keeps returning undefined?

Comment: Don't access anything in the constructor. Instead use the ngOnInit() method as bindings aren't processed in the constructor yet.

Comment: Still cannot access that var in the ngOnInit method.

Comment: Give me a sec to get behind a computer, typing on a phone now. It could be that the 'data-' attribute prefix gives it special meaning. Please try it without it.

Comment: I've confirmed that you can't use an attribute starting with `data-`. I've updated (and properly formatted) the answer.

Comment: This returns undefined :S

Comment: Very odd, I've added a plunkr link that shows a working example. Hopefully this will allow you to find out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I can't see where you set that attribute in that example :S

Comment: Sorry, it's added in src/app.ts at line 11

Comment: Ahh i see, i am currently building an app that uses stand alone components so i need to be able to add the attrs onto the the elements called in the main html file

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I'm happy you figured it out :)

Comment: Might have to go a different route by the looks of it

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pass data between components (from parent to child for example)
Here's a link with the different ways : [official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)
Hope that helps u :)

Comment: That didn't answer my question, nowhere on that page illustrates how to do what i want to do.

Comment: @Johnwilliams the `@Input()` decorator is covered in that documentation, while the answer is not great (borderline just a link) it did in fact contain the solution you ended up accepting!

Comment: Life is hard at times, i suggest you take it on the chin and just move on.

Comment: There are multiple solutions, I gave u the right link to choose the easy answer for u ;) You were going to make a little effort to find what @Robba wrote, m8