# Angular @Input is not working with bootstrap component

Tags: angular, angular2-inputs

I did a mistake in my Angular2 class and I've not clearly understood about **@Input**.

I created 2 components AppComponent and AppDetailComponent.

In AppDetailComponent :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component ({
selector: 'app-detail',
template: 'Hi {{datainput}}'
})

export class AppDetailComponent {

@Input()
datainput: string;

}
```

and in AppComponent template :

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<app-detail [datainput]="'test'"></app-detail>
```

and in App Module I made a mistake by add AppDetailComponent as bootstrap component

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppDetailComponent } from './app-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, AppDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, AppDetailComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After I removed AppDetailComponent from the bootstrap list, program was working correctly.

I don't understand 
why @input dose not working when I use it as bootstrap component?

Will Angular always ignore input property in spite of I send the input from an other angular component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Inputs()` can only be bound in templates of a component. Bootstrapped component are in `index.html` outside of any other component and therefore there it's not possible to bind to inputs.

See also [Angular 2 external inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152914/angular-2-external-inputs)

If you don't have a matching selector in `index.html` and don't want to use a component as root component, then don't add it to `bootstrap: [...]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly.
I didn't add input in index.html but app.component.html which declared as templateUrl of AppComponent

Comment: Why did you add `AppDetailComponent` to `bootstrap: []` then?

Comment: Thank you. I did a mistake but I want to know a reason. I try to check javascript file but  I found nothing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Angular just doesn't support input in root components and `bootstrap` is for registering root components. There is no point generating code for something that's not supposed to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bootstrap only the AppComponent.

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppDetailComponent } from './app-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AppDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```