# How to pass value to component from html?

Tags: angular

I want to pass a static value from html to component but it's just not  working, I have been stuck all day long... could you give me some glue? Thanks

component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-hello',
  template: `<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    <button (click)="greet()">Show Greet</button>
  `,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input()
  name: string;

  greet(){
    console.log(`Hello,${name}`);
  }
}
```

entry html index.html

```
<rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello>
```

What I'm expecting is  it can print **Hello, World** on the page and name property can be set to World in component, how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `this` to refer `name` since it is part of your instance of `HelloComponent`:

```
greet() {
  console.log(`Hello, ${this.name}`);
}
```

Your template looks fine.

**Edit:** Since you are using `@Input` in a bootstrapped component, it seems not possible to do so:

- [Angular @Input is not working with bootstrap component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42412634/2436655)
- [Angular 2 external inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33155688/2436655)

Comment: it's not really working even adding keyword this. Console says Hello,undefined , and page displays Hello,!, World just not got by component.

Comment: Can you add `<rio-hello name="World"></rio-hello>` to your app.component.html instead of index.html (where `<app-root></app-root>` should be in index.html)?

Comment: Yes, that should be working if I make the app component as bootstrap component and use rio-hello in app.component.html, but it's not my exact expectation , I hoped to give user a chance to directly set the name value on first place, index.html instead of parent component. I created a live angular project at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmzdeh where everyone can edit and run it online, maybe you could take a look. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Is it possible to get the property of a bootsrapped component which seems very useful? Suppose that app component need to parse a file whose name and path is configured on a property. Without the ability to get the path directly we are not able to parse it.  Seems likely @input is only working for data passing between parent and children components